# UWP C# failed linq search

Tags: c#, linq

I may get some downvotes for this Question, but I can't find my mistake here and I am happy for help.

The problem is that in my `List<string> names` there are names of movies which should be the same as the Name in `db.MovieModels` but everytime `item` with the same `name` as a `c` in my `db.MovieModels` should match `c` does not get selected. So my query stays empty.

Is there something wrong with my linq search?

(`db.MovieModels` contains Movies and I can see with breakpoints that for Example `item = "Pulp Fiction"` and a Movie in there is named `"Pulp Fiction"` but still an empty query.)

```
public static ListModel CreateLists(string name, DateTime date, List<string> names)
        {
             ObservableCollection<MovieModel> contained = new ObservableCollection<MovieModel>();
             // checks if the Movie Names from "names" are in the db
             foreach (var item in names)
             {
                 var query = from c in db.MovieModels
                             where c.Name == item
                             select c;
                 foreach (var t in query)
                 {
                     contained.Add(t);
                 }
             }
        ListModel a = new ListModel
            {
                ListName = name,
                DateOfCreation = date.Date,
                MoviesList = contained
            };
            return a;

    }
```

EDIT: Seems like i forgot the rest of the method

EDIT2: Here a look how the method is used.

```
CreateLists("Top 10 Rated - The Top Ten", new DateTime(2017, 5, 11), new List<string>
                {
                "The Godfather",
                "Forrest Gump",
                "The Shawshank Redemption",
                "The Dark Knight",
                "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King",
                "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back",
                "Pulp Fiction",
                "Titanic",
                "Saving Private Ryan",
                "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope",
                }));
```

Edit3:

A picture of 3 BP.

[image]

Edit4:

I ran loops for each `<MovieModel>`in `db.MovieModels`and compared them to the ´List names` and nothing!

I am using SQLite and I often use `Name` from MovieModels so I don't understand why it won't work.

Comment: Your method have some issues. First, I don't see any return statement, despite the fact that it's not declared as a `void`. Where the argument `name` is used? Last I have the same question regarding the `date` argument. Thanks !

Comment: I am sorry I forgot the rest of the method. See edit. Ty

Comment: Not a problem. Please check my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order you find the matched MovieModels you could declare the following query and request it's execution by calling `ToList`:

```
var matchedMovieModels = (from movieModel in db.MovieModels
                         join name in names                             
                         on movieModel.Name equals name
                         select movieModel).ToList();
```

Doing so you make only one round trip to the database ! Whereas looping through `names` and for each `name` trying to find which MovieModels can be matched you make as many round trips to the database as the `names.Length`.

**UPDATE**

```
public static ListModel CreateLists(string name, DateTime date, List<string> names)
{
    var matchedMovieModels = from movieModel in db.MovieModels
                             join name in names
                             on movieModel.Name equals name
                             select movieModel;
    return new ListModel
    {
        ListName = name,
        DateOfCreation = date.Date,
        MoviesList = new ObservableCollection<MovieModel>(matchedMovieModels)
    };
}
```

Comment: If I understand it corretly `matchedMovieModels` should only contain `MovieModels` which are in `names` (makes sense and is much better than looping trough everything) 
But the line I don't get is "join name in names" (it also tells me after `names`should be "equals" or "on" not "where").

Still ty

Comment: @DanielMaurer Yes, you understood correct ! oops...My bad...writing code out of visual studio :(. Thanks

Comment: I implemented the code, but still no matches.. So the mistake should be somewhere on the db.MovieModels side? (Can't think of anything, because the names match)

Comment: Seems like the issue was with me. I had `// db.SaveChanges`. So the linq couldn't "acces" the MovieModels. But ty for the better Code.

Comment: @DanielMaurer Ok (I assume that this call is made in another method, since in this method I don't see any reason of doing so). You are welcome !

Answer (score 0):

It appears to work in this code

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ObservableCollection<MovieModel> models = CreateLists("a", DateTime.Now, new List<string>() { "a", "c" });
        }
        public static ObservableCollection<MovieModel> CreateLists(string name, DateTime date, List<string> names)
        {
            MovieModel db = new MovieModel() { 
                MovieModels = new List<MovieModel>() {
                    new MovieModel() { Name ="a"},
                    new MovieModel() { Name ="b"},
                    new MovieModel() { Name ="c"}
                }
            };

            ObservableCollection<MovieModel> contained = new ObservableCollection<MovieModel>();
            // checks if the Movie Names from "names" are in the db
            foreach (var item in names)
            {
                var query = from c in db.MovieModels
                            where c.Name == item 
                            select c;
                foreach (var t in query)
                {
                    contained.Add(t);
                }
            }

            return contained;
        }
    }
    public class MovieModel
    {
        public List<MovieModel> MovieModels { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

    }

}
```

Comment: Any guesses where I went wrong? Still nothing on my side.

Comment: Did you set you db to anything?   The database is probable null

Comment: I had `// db.SaveChanges()` and forgot to save the Movies in the DB. 
Still ty.!